# Select portion of multiline text in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, selection

This is from an *Android Development Tutorial*. How can I select this portion of texts and change them at the same time?

[image]

Comment: In mac, hold `option` and select

Comment: I'm Windows user. but @onik solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up the context menu with the mouse/touchpad right button click and choose *Column Selection Mode* (Mac's screenshot):

[image]

Even more convenient, as [@rajan ks mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919756/select-portion-of-multiline-text-in-android-studio#comment116551299_65919756), for Mac hold `option` and select.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows to add and remove carets do `Shift` + `Alt` + Click

It is called Multi Cursor and full details can be found on the [official doc here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#multiple_cursor)

Answer (score 1):

in Mac its Shift + Command + 8